# View flat file in Windows command-line

Tags: windows, command-line

What is the Windows command-line command that is equivalent of Unix `More`?  I want to view some flat files under Windows' CMD prompt.

Comment: Wow! I didn't think there were still MS-DOS users out there...

Comment: That's **not** MS-DOS.

Comment: What's a flat file?

Comment: flat file is just a plain text file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been a while, but I think I used to do `type foo.txt | more`

Comment: If you are using cmd.exe try typing "more /?" for options ... you can include filenames there too

Comment: If you do that, the system will make a copy (and you are probably using floppy disks, so it will cost you if it works at all). Use `more < foo.txt`

Comment: @user26312: Since when?

Comment: @user26312: Since the question is not about MS-DOS but in fact Windows' cmd prompt, the file is not likely on a floppy disk.

Answer (score 1):

Even better: `more < foo.txt`

Comment: Even better: `more foo.txt`

Answer (score 1):

[Less](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/download.html#binaries) is available for Windows CMD.EXE (as well as Linux, FreeBSD, OS X, actual MS-DOS and others). It's *much* better than the default `more`.

For example `more` won't let you move back toward the beginning of a file; `less` will. (Some Linux and other versions of `more` have this and other features, though.)